# latex subfigure not centered

Tags: latex, overleaf

My code is as following but my figures are not centre aligned with captions. How can I fix it?

[code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmpJn.png)

```
   \begin{figure}[H]
       \centering
       \begin{subfigure}{0.7\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=4cm,height=6cm]{outwithsel.PNG} 
       \caption{Outliner}
       \label{fig:h1}
        \end{subfigure}
        
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{moveBtns.PNG}
        \caption{Buttons that move selected object in 4 different directions}
        \label{fig:h2}
        \end{subfigure}
     \caption{Kitchen is selected and can be moved to where desired}
```

Here somaia, that's what happens when I tried what you said. [fix from comment 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTviZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

Your images have the widths `4cm` and `.8\textwidth`, respectively. This means they are smaller than the `subfigure` around them. To get them centred inside the bigger `subfigure`, you need to repeat `\centering` inside the subfigure.

In addition there are missing `%` at the end of some of your lines. These unprotected line breaks will act like a space, and thus decentre your subfigure by a small amount (probably not noticeable, but when we are already at it...).

Unrelated to your problem: don't specify both the width and the height of the image, this will distort it. At least add `keepaspectratio` if you really must give both dimensions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=4cm,height=6cm]{example-image-duck} 
 \caption{Outliner}
 \label{fig:h1}
  \end{subfigure}%
  
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{Buttons that move selected object in 4 different directions}
  \label{fig:h2}
  \end{subfigure}%
\caption{Kitchen is selected and can be moved to where desired}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I think you have a problem in \texwidth, you have to choose the 0.5 textwidth  for each subfigure

Comment: doing that doesn't solve my problem. It actually also ruins the figure sizes, they got too small.  I can't add a picture here so I will add it in the next question itself. check it.

Answer (score -3):

This will solve your problem:

```
   \begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{Bloch sphere.PNG} 
   \caption{Outliner}
   \label{fig:h1}
    
    
    
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Bloch sphere.PNG}
    \caption{Buttons that move selected object in 4 different directions}
    \label{fig:h2}
    
 \caption{Kitchen is selected and can be moved to where desired}
```

\end{figure}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).